# Setting a default iframe source when using multiple iframes on a page?

Tags: html

The code below works great when you desire to load a different iframe source by clicking on a link.

```
<a href="first.html" target="myiframe">First Link</a>
<a href="second.html" target="myiframe">Second Link</a>
<a href="third.html" target="myiframe">Third Link</a>

<iframe name="myiframe"></iframe>
```

> My challenge is how to set a default iframe source before the user has time to click on the appropriate link.

Currently my page is empty until I click on the appropriate iframe link but I would like to load the first iframe by default (automatically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `src="first.html"` for `iframe` tag. And when the page is loaded, `first.html` will show in the `iframe`.

```
<a href="first.html" target="myiframe">First Link</a>
<a href="second.html" target="myiframe">Second Link</a>
<a href="third.html" target="myiframe">Third Link</a>

<iframe src="first.html" name="myiframe"></iframe>
```